# To show the value of object in openerp point of sale

Tags: odoo

I added a input box(#cus-in) in point of sale module.

myfun: function() {

```
        var dd=pos.store.get('product.product');

        $("#cus-in").val(dd);


        );
```

I wrote this code in pos.js.How can I show the value of dd object in input(#cus-in) view?I only viewed that [object Object] in input box of point of sale module.

Comment: try this $('#cus-in').val(dd.property-name);

Comment: here what will be property-name??is it mention a database field?suppose in product table there is a id field.for that i wrote$('#cus-in').val(dd.id);but it does not bring any object.it completely blank.

Comment: dd.toSource() shows the value of object.

Comment: ok,thanks.Atlast we have did it.

Answer (score 1):

dd is object on product.product module,

first print dd like
console.log("value of dd:::::", dd)
than after see in which formate values are come, in here I think comes list of products.